# wrong subtitle in a film

Tags: present-tense, perfect-constructions, continuous

In the film "Basse Normandie" of Simon Regiani and Patricia Mazuy, I saw this subtitle, is it possible

> I **have been working** while I **wait** for you

I think it should be:

> while I was waiting or while I **waited**

Because when the character said that sentence the wait was over but the character was still working.

Comment: I watch a lot of European "arthouse" movies and I think that translation of film subtitles is often done by native speakers of the original language. I often see minor errors like that, maybe more often in lower budget films.  Even in Scandi Noir TV dramas on big UK networks.

Comment: It would not be natural in written English, but it sounds fine to me in *conversational* English, in which things are often stated ungrammatically.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to tell exactly without seeing it.

That said, if someone knocks on my door as I'm answering this question, I would say to that person:

"**I've been working while waiting for you**". I don't know why subtitlers so often forget to use contractions.

That said: "**I've been working while I was waiting for you."** is OK, too.

I would not use: "while I wait for you" in this case, as that would be used for a general idea: While I wait for you every Thursday, you are always late.